# Galaxy role. The module file was not found in configured module paths. Additionally, core modules are missing

Tags: ansible

This is from a galaxy role (ashwin_sid.gaia_fw1) that I'm trying to implement.

Ansible version is 2.8.4

As part of the playbook it logs in, runs a show command. The output is then supposed to go to "BACKUP", but it throws this error: "The module file  was not found in configured module paths. Additionally, core modules are missing".

This is the playbook:

```
   serial: 1
   gather_facts: no
   tasks:
     - name: BACKUP
       import_role:
         name: ashwin_sid.gaia_fw1
         tasks_from: backup'
```

I think this where it breaks, where it references this file:

```
'- name: create dir
  local_action: file  path=={{ logdir | default('../BACKUP') }}/{{ r0.stdout }} state=directory'
```

This is the task with the error in verbose mode.

```
TASK [ashwin_sid.gaia_fw1 : create dir] ****************************************************************************************************************************************************************
task path: /app/sandbox/playbooks/ashwin_sid.gaia_fw1/tasks/backup.yml:23
<localhost> ESTABLISH LOCAL CONNECTION FOR USER: xxxxx
<localhost> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'echo ~xxxxx && sleep 0'
<localhost> EXEC /bin/sh -c '( umask 77 && mkdir -p "` echo /home/xxxxx/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1569528903.45-71335581192935 `" && echo ansible-tmp-1569528903.45-71335581192935="` echo /home/xxxxx/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1569528903.45-71335581192935 `" ) && sleep 0'
fatal: [lab_B]: FAILED! => {
    "msg": "The module file  was not found in configured module paths. Additionally, core modules are missing. If this is a checkout, run 'git pull --rebase' to correct this problem."
}
```

I'm not sure what other information to provide?

I've created the "BACKUP" directory. I don't think it's a permissions issue. It logs in fine and I think it runs the command it just can't write?

Comment: Which version of ansible are your running ? `import_role` was introduced in ansible 2.7. If this is not the problem, can you show the exact error in its context when your run the playbook (edit your question above). Moreover, missing core modules would indicate a problem with your global ansible installation. Did you try to reinstall it ? Or to install it from scratch in a python virtualenv to see if it fixes the problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an extra space in your playbook:

```
  "local_action: file  path=={{"
```

should be :

```
  "local_action: file path=={{
```

The error shows an extra space after stating module not found:

> '"msg": "The module file  was not found...'

After removing that space, it should work for you.